# Print A-Z and their alphabet index without using 1,2,4,6

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

You need to print A-Z like this:

```
1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D
5. E
6. F
7. G
8. H
9. I
10. J
11. K
12. L
13. M
14. N
15. O
16. P
17. Q
18. R
19. S
20. T
21. U
22. V
23. W
24. X
25. Y
26. Z
```

But your source code cannot use `1,2,4,6`.

Trailing newlines in output allowed,, but leading ones not allowed.

Standard loopholes apply, shortest code wins.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of many existing [tag:restricted-source] [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] "print X without Y" challenges, and the ban on `1` `2` `4` and `6` is arbitrary and unchallenging,

Comment: In future, please use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) to get feedback on your question before posting.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
i=8*8
while i<90:i=-~i;print`i-8*8`+'. %c'%i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWQsuCqzwjMydVIdPG0sAq01a3LtO6oCgzryQhUxcomaCtrqegmqyumvn/PwA)

**46 bytes**

```python
i=0
while i<33-7:i=-~i;print'%d. %c'%(i,i+8*8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgKs8IzMnVSHTxthY19wq01a3LtO6oCgzr0RdNUVPQTVZXVUjUydT20LLQvP/fwA)

The loop condition can also be `while-~i/9-3:` or `while~-i/5-5` or `while-i/5-~5:` or `while~-i-5*5:` or `while~-033>i`.

**46 bytes**

```python
i=0
exec 78/3*"i=-~i;print'%d. %c'%(i,i+8*8);"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgCu1IjVZwdxC31hLKdNWty7TuqAoM69EXTVFT0E1WV1VI1MnU9tCy0LTWun/fwA)

**46 bytes**

```python
i=8*8
while i<90:i=-~i;print'%d. %c'%(i-8*8,i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWQsuCqzwjMydVIdPG0sAq01a3LtO6oCgzr0RdNUVPQTVZXVUjUxeoSidT8/9/AA)

**46 bytes**

```python
i=0
while~i-5*5:i=~-i;print'%d. %c'%(-i,8*8-i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgKs8IzMntS5T11TL1CrTtk4307qgKDOvRF01RU9BNVldVUM3U8dCy0I3U/P/fwA)

**46 bytes**

```python
i=8*8
while i<90:i=-~i;print'%d. %c'%(i&799,i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWQsuCqzwjMydVIdPG0sAq01a3LtO6oCgzr0RdNUVPQTVZXVUjU83c0lInU/P/fwA)

**47 bytes**

```python
for i in range(33-7):print"%d. %c"%(-~i,8*8-~i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9hY11zTqqAoM69ESTVFT0E1WUlVQ7cuU8dCywJIaf7/DwA)

Comment: @ovs The issue is that 1's are banned

Comment: Does [this work](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWQsuCqzwjMydVIdPG0sAq01a3LtO6oCgzryQhUxcomaCtrqegmqyumvn/PwA) for 44 bytes?

Comment: @dingledooper Yes, I had just gotten exactly that too

Answer (score 6):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 27 bytes

```sh
eval ';echo $[++i]. '{A..Z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/tSwxR0HdOjU5I19BJVpbOzNWT0G92lFPL6r2/38A)

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 48 bytes

```javascript
f=(n=033)=>--n?f(n)+n+`. ${Buffer([8*8|n])}
`:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoIwFADQd79iSOC9ybQyQgIL@g0RHLpbi3EX27SH6tvXOU@1qjB584qS3axTog642zUNdhcp@UrAWHI5VmLzuS1E2kPfbtsvD/jLxnNRJENQ9/vD8TTUVdQhAiGK@PDuLXLDq7JmFsEtftJ5NjkOzurKujsQIKY/)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 19 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

```apl
↑(⍳∘≢,⍥⍕¨'. '∘,¨)⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94P@jtokaj3o3P@qY8ahzkc6j3qWPeqceWqGup6AOFNI5tELzUd9UR5DS/wpgUAAA)

`⎕A` the uppercase **A**lphabet

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function:

`'. '∘,¨` prepend ". " to each letter.

`,⍥⍕¨` concatenate the string representation of each to the string representation of:

`⍳∘≢` the **ɩ**ndices of the length of the alphabet

`↑` "mix" the list of strings into a character matrix

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>45</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```php
for($c=A;$c<>AA;$c++)echo++$i,". $c
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFSSbR2tVZJt7BxBlLa2ZmpyRr62tkqmjpKegkoyl5L1//8A)

-1 thanks to [Kaddath](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90841/kaddath)

Comment: The new line can be a "literal" new line in the string [like this](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFSSbR2tVZJt7BxBlLa2ZmpyRr62tkqmjpKegkoyl5L1//8A) to save 1 byte

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
Auā'.«sø»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fsfRIo7reodXFh3cc2v3/PwA)

```python
A          # push the lowercase alphabet
 u         # convert to uppercase
  ā        # push the range [1 .. len(alphabet)]
   '.«    '# append '.' to each number
      s    # swap to the alphabet
       ø   # zip both lists => [['1.', 'A'], ..., ['26.', 'Z']]
        »  # join each inner list by spaces and the outer list by newlines
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Ｅα⁺⁺⊕κ. ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUAjUUchIKe0WANMeOYlF6XmpuaVpKZoZGvqKCjpKSgBqUxNTU3r////65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 α          Predefined variable uppercase alphabet
Ｅ           Map over characters
     κ      Current index (0-indexed)
    ⊕       Incremented
      .     Literal string `. `
        ι   Current character
  ⁺⁺        All concatenated
            Implicitly print on separate lines
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5.10](https://www.perl.org/), 22 bytes

```perl
say++$..". $_"for A..Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbW0VPT0lPQSVeKS2/SMFRTy/q//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DA30DAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 33 bytes

```r
write.table(LETTERS,,,F,". ",c=F)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVryQxKSdVw8c1JMQ1KFhHR8dNR0lPQUkn2dZN8/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｚ｛²Ｏ. ｏｏ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjVCJUIyJXVGRjJGLiUyMCV1RkY0RiV1RkY0Rg__,v=8), [alternate version](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjVCJUIyLiUyMCV1MjUxOCV1RkYwOSV1RkYzRA__,v=8)

The only reason this is shorter than charcoal is because it's got a 1-indexed iteration count.

### Explanation

```
Z{²O. oo
Z{       loop over the alphabet
  ²O     output the iteration number
    . o  output ". "
       o output the current letter
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>49</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
T`@L`_o
}`$
Z
.
$.`. $&¶
A`@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JMHBJyE@n6s2QYUrikuPS0UvQU9BRe3QNi7HBIf//wE) Explanation:

```
T`@L`_o
}`$
Z
```

Generate the uppercase alphabet prefixed by `@`. This works by feeding in `Z`s and transliterating a step backwards each time until the transformation becomes idempotent.

```
.
$.`. $&¶
```

Prefix each character with its 0-based index and `.` , and split each character on to its own line.

```
A`@
```

Delete the `@` entry.

Comment: You have a `1` that snuck in

Comment: @xnor Luckily Retina 0.8.2 gives me an alternate way of referring to that capture group!

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 25 bytes

```powershell
'A'..'Z'|%{++$i;"$i. $_"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X91RXU9PPUq9RrVaW1sl01pJJVNPQSVeqfb/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [BASIC](http://www.yabasic.de), 41 bytes

```
for i=!0 to 33-7:?i,". ",chr$(8*8+i):next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/Py2/SCHTVtFAoSRfwdhY19zKPlNHSU9BSSc5o0hFw0LLQjtT0yovtaLk/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 41 bytes

```powershell
(8-7)..(33-7)|%{"$($_). "+[char]($_+8*8)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NC11xTT0/D2BhI16hWK6loqMRr6ikoaUcnZyQWxQJ52hZaFpq1//8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>52</del> 50 bytes

```python
for x in range(8-7,33-6):print(f"{x}.",chr(x+8*8))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1Vw0LXXMfYWNdM06qgKDOvRCNNqbqiVk9JJzmjSKNC20LLQlPz/38A)

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1Vw0LXXMfYVNdC06qgKDOvRCNNqbqiVk9JJzmjSKNC20LLQlPz/38A)

Comment: @ovs thanks for that!

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1VQytJyTFaSdOqoCgzr0QjTam6QtdCy6JWT0E1WUm1QvP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (Browser console), 58 bytes

```
for(i=0;i<35-9;)alert(++i+". "+String.fromCharCode(i+8*8))
```

-2 bytes thanks to @expressjs123
-3 bytes thanks to @tsh

Comment: 67 bytes: `for(i=8-7;i<35-8;i++)console.log(i+". "+String.fromCharCode(i+8*8))`

Comment: 64 bytes: `for(i=0;i<35-9;)console.log(++i+". "+String.fromCharCode(i+8*8))`

Comment: @tsh thanks for it

Comment: @expressjs123 thanks for it

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `j`, 10 bytes

```
αɾkAZƛı. j
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%CE%B1%C9%BEkAZ%C6%9B%C4%B1.%20j&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 27 bytes

```
3*9*@
Y`@`L_
L$`.
$.>`. $&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8tYy1LLgSsywSHBJ57LRyVBj0tFzy5BT0FF7f9/AA) Explanation:

```
3*9*@
```

Insert 27 `@`s. (Best I can do since I can't use `2` or `6`.)

```
Y`@`L_
```

Replace each `@` with subsequent uppercase letters, but delete the last one.

```
L$`.
```

Match each letter.

```
$.>`. $&
```

For each letter, output its 1-indexed index, `.` , then the letter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ØAĖj€⁾. Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMcj07IeNa151LhPTyHy/38A)

### How it works

```
ØAĖj€⁾. Y - Main link. Takes no arguments
ØA        - Yield the uppercase alphabet and set as the left and right arguments
  Ė       - Enumerate
   j€⁾.   - Join each pair with ". "
        Y - Join with newlines and output
```

Comment: `Ė` saves 1 over `Jż`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
;B£[YÄLSXR]q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/39rp0OLoyMMtPsERQbGF//8DAA)

Straightforward, though I feel like there's still room for improvement.

Explanation:

```
;B£[YÄLSXR]q    #
;               # Store the uppercase alphabet in B
 B£             # Replace each character in B with the following:
   [      ]     #  Make an array containing:
    YÄ          #   The 0-based index of the character + 1 (i.e. 1-based index)
      L         #   Period
       S        #   Space
        X       #   The original character
         R      #   A newline
           q    #  Join the array into a string with no separator
                # Implicitly output the resulting string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://rust-lang.org/), 56 bytes

```rust
||for(i,x)in(9..).zip('A'..'['){print!("{}. {}
",i-8,x)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 62 bytes

```
$->{for(char c='@';++c<'[';)System.out.println(c-'@'+". "+c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwFETX5hSfUlAr5gKppdB1V0I30kX6qzY2JpL8CEU8u83C2QzzZphBzrIc3t9NjZN1BEPMPJDSvAsGSVnDT4JN4aUVAmrpPdylMgtLduZJUrTZqjeMsclqcsr0zROk632@MNiV3KzxYWzd@RG3F@iq7Vhels66DD/SAVbpNRVFgee0SUVe/zy1I7eB@BQPSZsMy7goDhwOBeZi3QRLko5LxHaizASt80hWtm5/)

## Java, 95 bytes

```
$->java.util.stream.IntStream.range('A','[').forEach(i->System.out.println(i-'@'+". "+(char)i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LasMwEEXX1leIEJDUxPqBNKaldJFFVoZuQhdTRXbG1cNIo0AJ@XZX0EBnc@eeGTgTXKGdzt8L@jkm4lPtuhA6PZRgCGPQTzs2ly@HhhsHOfMjYLix5sEyAdW4RjxzXy@yp4RhPH1ySGNWN8Yf07zFkIu36fmj/nZ82C/rtvv3ZUoWvD4E6v@2BGG0UryKrTgJpYeY3sFcJLZd/5PJeh0L6bnKyIVKxYvYrDRfbaS5QFKo1LJjTTNoMMbOJENxTlVyZ/flFw)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua (55 bytes)

```
for i=7%3,33-7 do print(i..". "..(8*8+i..""):char())end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 41 bytes

```bash
echo {A..Z}|tr ' ' '
'|nl -s". " -w$[8-7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1@h2lFPL6q2pqRIQR0EudRr8nIUdIuV9BSUFHTLVaItdM1j//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>37</s></sup> 35 bytes

```julia
'A':'Z'.|>i->print("$(i-'@'). $i
")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X91R3Uo9Sl2vxi5T166gKDOvRENJRSNTV91BXVNPQSWTS0nz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;B¬ËiSiLiEÄ
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0Ksy2lTaUxpRcQ)

Comment: Nice. The closest I got without `;` was 13 [`26Ç°Ä+". {ZdI`](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=MjbHsMQrIi4ge1pkSQ)

Comment: @noodleman, [12 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=Mjb1XytkSSBpU2ku)

Comment: Ooh, clever! I've lost all my epic Japt skillz already >:(

Answer (score 0):

## C

```
main() { for(int i='A',j=0;i<='Z';j++,printf("%d. %c\n",j,i),i++);}
```

If for some, this wouldn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() { for(int i='A',j=0;i<='Z';j++,printf("%d. %c\n",j,i),i++);}
```

Comment: Maybe not the shortest, But I have tried to make it as short as possible,  Wishes from Sweden!

Comment: using `void main` will give a warning, but allow you to omit `return 0`.

Comment: You're not allowed to use `1`, but you can use `j=0` and `++j` instead.

Comment: @Neil Oh my gosh, thanks for pointing that out - I totally didn't pay attention, will edit !

Comment: Why not remove the spaces? Also you can change `i<='Z'` to `i<'['` and put the `j++` and `i++` inside the `printf` call, and remove the `=0` because `j` will be initialised to `0` implicitly

Comment: @pxeger I know it will as a global, but not as a local surely?

Comment: @Neil I'm not a C expert so I'm not sure, but it seems to work on GCC - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6Lb9IIzOvRCHTVt1RXSfLOtNGPVrduqAIKJamoaSaoqegmhyTp6SjrZ2lk6mtralpXfv/PwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Neil Oh sorry I didn't saw the notification - wow sorry; will edit obviously! Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @pxeger Hmm, well, I guess it depends on the exact compiler and optimisation level... which fortunately is valid in code golf.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
f(i){for(i=0;++i<033;)printf("%d. %c\n",i,i+'@');}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcHBCkBAEADQu6/YlMy0VspxKR/iotFsUyyhHDa/bniPXCBSZRBMvB0gfeOtla5pW4/7IfFiyIu5NgWNMa@kElsOJfpH10kioEmZ@TGgzx59iZcpnOruDw)

Comment: You are missing the space after the dot and you can save 1 byte with `f(i)`

Comment: @SheikYerbouti Fixed, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
main(i){for(;i<3*9;printf("%d. %c\n",i++,i+8*8));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOi2/SMM608ZYy9K6oCgzryRNQ0k1RU9BNTkmT0knU1sbiC20LDQ1rWv//wcA)

```c
f(i){for(i=0;++i<3*9;printf("%d. %c\n",i,i+8*8));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1sBaWzvTxljL0rqgKDOvJE1DSTVFT0E1OSZPSSdTJ1PbQstCU9O69j9QTiE3MTNPQ1OhmotLAQjSNDStuWr/AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>9</s></sup> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
τ┌Z*µ╝╘Q
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e7da5a2ae6bcd451&i=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
j.e+++hk\.dbrG1
```

[Try it online!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=j.e%2B%2B%2Bhk%5C.dbrG1&debug=0)

---

Python 3 translation:

```
G = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz"

print("\n".join(map(lambda(k,b):str(k+1)+"."+" "+b,enumerate(G.upper()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 27 bytes

```apl
⎕∘←¨⎕a,⍨¨{'. ',⍨⍕⍵}¨⍳⎕a⍳'Z'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EcdMx61TTi0AshM1HnUu@LQimp1PQV1EPNR79RHvVtrgXK9m0HSQEo9Sv3/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 38 bytes

```
;=a 0W>+*5 5TaO+++''=a++0Ta'. 'A+*8 8a
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVhpc9u2Fv3@fgXMphYh0rSc6RbTtCdxnTeZ18hp7DbTJykRCEISG4pUuNhOJfavp/eCG6jN6RcPBRzcDecu8J/sjiU89hfpURh54gsPWJKQ/4X@dJZexXEUE/GQitBLiPy1zAvAGxYnor2vnKlQb7Mw9eeP427SWLD5kkdhksYZT6NYZ3SZzvzESqIs5sJhOez4i3czPxXJgnGhl/tzlvKZfvxeHwxHw8EwgfX8dGSsvhm8H4ajrj4MV08o7R7TfCHER9iNRZrFIVGED3qj1SrMgiAvhLkmd3p0GYiUMMe1xIPgugKndikCjziOwy7w41SFOMq3lWQu2K4zUGMFIpymM2qyAR/RPI3AcT@cbrUqz2U4yO0fb65unMHILkL1OwsysUxSlvqcLPAWdJcuXWsjPPYEonjHYvChZ7MzKabUbzPDKPzjjlwfsJFVybL9ic5paQ/PFV/zOAtl2OPonoTivmBE7gk3m25Z3@GdFGI1m4DrZ3NXxDtw1SbgXkRRIFi4A1jv5iWrfoFgxCyoiVeEbo1kSbZA6aYU9cFjKQOuFY4qSrY4U/5uzm3zpPzdBm24US2oMPEpQPNKBCM@WM1CLqJJ4bXixuGhYjzwsfiqooDC6xCUIdngT8X1JptuX47o4PnR/0fdY/Okpjw7PMQLRpm6dquhNpp72XxROzOunHki8zOn4zxIZ40rB42th4esdW1TFUdU3EEbmBdkXmTJTMdVahepctX//dXb6/7rq/6ts8zLhHnliTBd48Bj7g/Y0V8fRvi3d/TsA4RgPQBSKBib72OTjyBgUzs@8qg/8QFXhKjAYaDAXH8aohzFk0GDGdXULAzegcIMvot8j/QO8H4qy@0mQdW6rI9/Cz@G0X1I/Noy0mmZ1hm3Yy5doFV8leh@Lb2GnrEZUghomS6MrpOq3Gg4xTxP4Up1vuGMwZTSQXOowXvhR234PAv2wrttuOffqV42W3gTrUuoRL1m6cwC3oRckXoMfu@6JO2ShWGUElAFd0Lcz@QvEUcamBp5/1J3o/Bb9qg@EJ8FkaJvEd3v19eIX60OdHbWo1/lfLf7Fd6Lh0UUIklZKqRBJI2gNoZiCny7EwSMEzEYGeyoJGfqve2sN@ctVIv4De370BD3816p3jXx@2VJpQXnUUirhFQVBNvtWg5oCNaptq8zSHml84@EkkdzMFPII5ZWB@NfnlKDg2tVdKA5PhocpJDrMKXnaJ0RhTkuGd6Muhd0eHJsPpW0wmgAs1yVSKABh5ViiGFWMdwhWOtgW@KrVUfr4AdtXGqGVix6YNXcD4FJHvmURUAoEfIow2XhnZInS5aPt7V0aX87j8yTHl2tems1qxwQ9tUsdGJcAkqFm6UHQY0uKxYLwaD3qBXoEcbXo9Zextco9VJhseyucIp5N59DfspyJxafMj8WujZJNGoucUSWW66yxWd@4H1YxBEXCaJe/ta/vH113b9pevNLqAH7WrPCkuKCYTKvxQxcpdPJm1ZmVVvh1cWpzDpjZdHjgjEC52mcj/GHB/Oxd8ar2dirZuOJIy2yKlNQ2cFkB51e@9C7wylh8TSb48DxZOkZJzkBJWSCXkJHdbGR2qII7ITmyh1jIHRuuqZYGylgia@NFSjOYcV3yObCcYtvUJ04fHN2lQd0y7JqVF1ZiiquofbUj0JdM2qpdXhcUo2c8igzHM0kmuFahYy6ixvaRm26dv8UPLX8RPLXhHEpn5SqSCymfpIK6SJdQmhPsFdVD6S1t4Su9cEkMs9gyHMhUR8YT4PPBHoB4TMWwy@YWYIonEJNshuCsJHjKhohMHXnUq@2TDJ4gequkgdUrT3NGFW8N@ytNND6EblDyVAos8BDW6UK7wBqpZJVGHBq1iHQ3mimTp3z8kmmaabrvMgmExFbLAgirsMA7kUYJKb3gBE9mMhNoLwLT0rqguEfbW6Aq/eQcUI/gS4sd@RLzsLceudD4mvDUKOUO9xKAh9eiD2THDWTfVVpOM1Vy94WlrVa9ySIwNfvnj777tkPPz599kNXrsYs9KI5hk09f6WZzDnHkLFWaBtI53kHIXWiF@EtrXLV7gYGXFRmFpKsSRzNL4EBl5EHg2b5dqKnlbnqdVq8xD1PcWZTjXwhjWTq0mWxVD4u5V91eyy36z7Udm6Ho9qv8lBZEC3x4K9XcQV7UCuQb632A6iF/KVGoseqIVUyqeifkVvn9fjWCnZlWZJ6UZZa9zE0bhBY5Dk1WStm121BjdZSmjYcyudh9e8PoNrFDgUlomdW6Q9YeroVPMYu@Z8xNevpSbXJALJiOWkuDltu6WUrDEcbSHwhbEN2N5DYobchjzeQ8l2wBfntpsxou53vN5By/t6CPKuRNWmqIzgb1EfUM@e7z0x3nbnYfQaL/9Yzh/UZnVUZ3vqPzUV57LSVg6tHj7FTdzM3beVYsWtuC5ijwFpVBh@3qxWoVB767ZRmVvlSd51av9sS/q4WvsQ@arfS16ZribeVzK8KEdD@nXO2NVh80/f/Kodk0Bq7Tbf1XDOxESg/q1pWpyMKWa00rR21m1KBJ1VUhx5R5TnepuYaXGU9DvgXzID5sqkILjW40ZhkeNiVm9bxd0etfe1HPOAgOuMvtsNI79250f2efH/Lrg3D6HQcZhi9W9axSOe50f2J/MS@jOFF6mP7sr/8Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) 0.3.1, 23 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247669/i-want-8-bits-for-every-character/265917#265917)

```
∵(&p$"_. _":+@@.)⊝⊚⇡ⁿ.3
```

[See it in action](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__4oi1KCZwJCJfLiBfIjorQEAuKeKKneKKmuKHoeKBvy4zCg==)